# Ext4 partition bigger than 2TB?

Tags: debian, partition, filesystems, ext4

Is there a way to make partition bigger than 2 TB on ext4 file system ?? Im trying to do that on debian but get message Partition size can not exceed 2TB ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is not a limitation of ext4, but a limitation of the MSDOS partition table format you are using.

You'll need to switch to [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partition tables. Use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) or [parted](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/) to create a GPT partition table on your disk. This will allow you to create partitions bigger than 2 TB.

fdisk doesn't work with GPT and won't let you have >2TB partitions.

Comment: ... or [GPT fdisk](http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/).

Answer (score 6):

You can, but MBR can't allow disk to be more that 2TB. You have to switch your partition table to [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)